# The resulting path is not the same

Tags: r

For storing R-related user-specific cache files. I replaced rappdirs::user_cache_dir() dependency with tools::R_user_dir() but the resulting path is not same. Can anyone help?

Comment: Maybe this issue helps: https://github.com/r-lib/rappdirs/issues/27

Comment: I tried using tools::R_user_dir(package name, which="cache") but still the path is False.

Comment: They aren't the same. The functions were written by different people at different times, and there is no standard or doctrine to dictate which (if either) one is more correct. They both are consistent within their own circles. While `tools::R_user_dir` (R-4 and later) defaults (on windows) to the `./AppData/Roaming/` directory (and can be changed to `./AppData/Local/` with `which="cache"`), they both choose (for whatever reason) vastly different subdirs. Lacking "standards" or "normal", I'm curious why one would assume they should match.

Comment: If you want/need to shift away from `rappdirs::` for this but want to preserve the subdir notion it defaults to, then I suggest you wrap the `tool::` function to remove its subdirs and replace with what you need.